# Hidden Markov models with state transitions conditioned on some node

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I'm lacking some clarity related to HMM's

Suppose I have a binomial state node and another binomial observation node,

In this node the conditional probability table will be 
state transition matrix with 4 values and emission matrix for observations.
Effectively I have 4(transition)+4(emission) parameters, but what happens if I condition the state node on some multinomial node with some 10 values, how many parameters are there in this case? How do I train this; I mean what changes are required?